# error while inserting python dataframe to mysql

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, sqlalchemy

**Here is the Python code:**

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd

mydb = create_engine("mysql://xx:xx@localhost/xx")
df = pd.DataFrame({'name' : ['User P', 'User Q', 'User R']})
df.to_sql('CARS', con=mydb)
```

**Error:**

> ProgrammingError: (_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError) (1064, "You
>   have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to
>   your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s, %s)'
>   at line 1") [SQL: INSERT INTO CARS (`index`, name) VALUES (%s, %s)]
>   [parameters: ((0, 'User P'), (1, 'User Q'), (2, 'User R'))]
>   (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/f405)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, so apparently it seems I had to install PyMySQL (python3 -m pip install PyMySQL)

And a little change here:

```
mydb = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://xx:xx@localhost/xx")
```

It worked after this. :)